# nant build file builts with nant 0.86 and not with 0.91 alpha 2

Tags: compiler-errors, nant

An extract from my console

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\miralp>cd\

C:>cd SVN

C:\SVN>..\Tools\nant-0.91-alpha2\bin\nant.exe -buildfile:C:\SVN\BestFareFinderGit\Source\Deploy\Functions.build
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\SVN>Tools\nant-0.91-alpha2\bin\nant.exe -buildfile:C:\SVN\BestFareFinderGit\Source\Deploy\Functions.build
NAnt 0.91 (Build 0.91.3881.0; alpha2; 17/08/2010)
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Gerry Shaw
http://nant.sourceforge.net

Buildfile: file:///C:/SVN/BestFareFinderGit/Source/Deploy/Functions.build
Target framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0

BUILD FAILED

C:\SVN\BestFareFinderGit\Source\Deploy\Functions.build(4,3):
Compilation failed:
c:\Users\miralp\AppData\Local\Temp\izhn5siv.0.cs(36,6) : error CS0012: The type 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.
Xml, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.239
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using NAnt.Core;
using NAnt.Core.Attributes;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

[FunctionSet("ttl", "ttl")]
public class nant84cd7051c5eb497da059d002e13b0448 : NAnt.Core.FunctionSetBase {

```
[Function("expand_nant_properties_into_template")]
public string Expand_nant_properties_into_template(string templateFilepath, string propertiesFilepath, string applicationVersion)
{
 const int INDENT_LEVEL = 0;
 const string APPLICATION_VERSION = "applicationVersion";

 //Get the contents of the template to be expanded
 string template = new FileInfo(templateFilepath)
        .OpenText()
        .ReadToEnd();

 //Create a new NAnt project with only the properties in the properties file
 Project project = new Project(propertiesFilepath, Level.None, INDENT_LEVEL);
 project.Properties.Add(APPLICATION_VERSION, applicationVersion);

 //Load the properties into memory
 project.Run();

 return project.Properties.ExpandProperties(template, Location.UnknownLocation);
}


public nant84cd7051c5eb497da059d002e13b0448(NAnt.Core.Project project, NAnt.Core.PropertyDictionary propDict) :
        base(project, propDict) {
}
```

}

Total time: 1.4 seconds.

C:\SVN>Tools\nant\bin\nant.exe -buildfile:C:\SVN\BestFareFinderGit\Source\Deploy\Functions.build
NAnt 0.86 (Build 0.86.2898.0; beta1; 08/12/2007)
Copyright (C) 2001-2007 Gerry Shaw
http://nant.sourceforge.net

Buildfile: file:///C:/SVN/BestFareFinderGit/Source/Deploy/Functions.build
Target framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5

[script] Scanning assembly "jp-pfatj" for extensions.
   [script] Scanning assembly "rzb29ihl" for extensions.

BUILD SUCCEEDED

Total time: 4.8 seconds.

C:\SVN>..\Tools\nant-0.91-alpha2\bin\nant.exe -buildfile:C:\SVN\BestFareFinderGit\Source\Deploy\Functions.build

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using the msbuild nant task.

Try setting the `nant.settings.currentframework` property like this:

```
<property name="nant.settings.currentframework" value="net-3.5" />
```